# Combinations from recursive lists

Tags: r

Suppose I have three words: `"blue"`, `"red"` and `"pink"`.

I wish to generate all combinations of letters where I take two letters out of "blue", then add to two letters out of "red", and then add to two letters out of "pink", e.g.

`blrdpk`

`uerdin`

etc...

In R, I have coded my three words by assigning the characters of each word into a list element using

```
words <- list( list("b","l","u","e"),  list("r","e","d"),  list("p","i","n","k") )
```

I know I can use `lapply` with `combn(words[[i]],m=2)` to get all combinations of 2 letters from each word.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a more advanced version of combn() which allows you to choose and concatenate combinations from different 'buckets' given using recursive lists?
2. If there is no advanced version of combn(), what is the best way of concatenating each of the separate 2 letter combinations from each of the three words?
3. Is there a simple way to do it if I wanted a different number of letters from each word? [Added from user comment in one of the answer]

Comment: Does order of the letters matter?

Comment: Order of the letters does not matter.

Comment: Also, I was just reading, and to answer question 2, I can probably just use expand.grid()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be more advanced versions of `combn`, but it's pretty advanced already. For example, you can apply a function to each combination by specifying the `FUN` argument. Combine this with expand.grid and Reduce and you'll wind up with something like

```
Reduce(paste0, expand.grid(lapply(words, function(x) {
  combn(x, m=2, FUN=paste0, collapse="")
})))
```

**Edit:**
If the number of letters to be selected from each word varies, this number can be added as an attribute of each element of the words list, then use that attribute as the `m` argument to `combn`. For example, to select one letter for the first word, two letters from the second, and three letters from the third:

```
for(i in seq_along(words)) {
  attr(words[[i]], "n") <- i
}

Reduce(paste0, expand.grid(lapply(words, function(x) {
  combn(x, m=attr(x, "n"), FUN=paste0, collapse="")})))
```

Alternatively you can use mapply as in geektrader's answer.

Comment: thanks. Is there a simple way to do it if I wanted a different number of letters from each word?

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution going from list of words and list of number of characters to be picked from each word to desired result

```
> words
[1] "blue" "red"  "pink"
> wordsplit <- strsplit(words, split="")
> wordsplit
[[1]]
[1] "b" "l" "u" "e"

[[2]]
[1] "r" "e" "d"

[[3]]
[1] "p" "i" "n" "k"

> lengths <- c(2, 1, 3)
> combos <- expand.grid(mapply(function(word, n) combn(word,m=n, FUN=paste0, collapse=""), wordsplit, lengths))
> head(combos)
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1   bl    r  pin
2   bu    r  pin
3   be    r  pin
4   lu    r  pin
5   le    r  pin
6   ue    r  pin

> do.call('paste0', combos)
 [1] "blrpin" "burpin" "berpin" "lurpin" "lerpin" "uerpin" "blepin" "buepin" "beepin" "luepin" "leepin" "ueepin" "bldpin" "budpin" "bedpin" "ludpin"
[17] "ledpin" "uedpin" "blrpik" "burpik" "berpik" "lurpik" "lerpik" "uerpik" "blepik" "buepik" "beepik" "luepik" "leepik" "ueepik" "bldpik" "budpik"
[33] "bedpik" "ludpik" "ledpik" "uedpik" "blrpnk" "burpnk" "berpnk" "lurpnk" "lerpnk" "uerpnk" "blepnk" "buepnk" "beepnk" "luepnk" "leepnk" "ueepnk"
[49] "bldpnk" "budpnk" "bedpnk" "ludpnk" "ledpnk" "uedpnk" "blrink" "burink" "berink" "lurink" "lerink" "uerink" "bleink" "bueink" "beeink" "lueink"
[65] "leeink" "ueeink" "bldink" "budink" "bedink" "ludink" "ledink" "uedink"
```