# Combinations from grouped elements

Tags: r, combinations

I have a list of grouped elements and I want to make all possible combinations of these elements, however I only want to take one element from each group. Order does not matter.

```
vars_list <- list(Group1 = letters[1:5],  Group2 = letters[6:9],
                    Group3 = letters[10:11], Group4 = letters[12:15])
```

Let's say I want to make combinations for n=2, n=3, n=4 where n is the number of groups I want to use.

I found a solution to do it when n=number of groups ([Combinations from recursive lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079503/combinations-from-recursive-lists)) :

```
lengths <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)
combos <- expand.grid( mapply(function(element, n) combn(element, m=n,
FUN=paste0, collapse=""), vars_list, lengths, SIMPLIFY = F) )
```

How could I do this for n < number of groups?

Comment: If n=2 where are the elements to be taken? `Group1` and `Group3`, `Group2` and `Group3` and so on?

Comment: Note that your `combos` is just the same as `expand.grid(vars_list)`, check `all(combos == expand.grid(vars_list))`

Comment: adiana, n=2 would mean two elements should be taken from two separate Groups eg. 'a' from Group1 and 'f' from Group2. user1981275, it is! looks like your answer does the job. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `combn` for getting all combinations of your groups for n=1, n=2, n=3 and n=4 and then use `expand_grid`:

```
n = 2
apply(combn(1:length(vars_list), n), 2, function(x){expand.grid(vars_list[x])})
```

so for n=4, you would get the same as in your question. Is this what you meant?

Comment: or, if you want a list for all `n` in one go, you could wrap it in another `lapply`: `lapply(1:4, function(n){apply(combn(1:length(vars_list), n), 2, function(x){expand.grid(vars_list[x])})})`
`